# How to use context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Does anyone knows in C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 why statement after the commented one in the following code does not work?
entityFramework core throws an exception

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (44ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET IDENTITY_INSERT @p0 ON;
```

By the way, commented statement works. And I am not running 2 statement together.

```
var tableName = "discountTypes";
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
//  context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT discountTypes ON;");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT {tableName} ON;");
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT discounTypes OFF;");
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Thank you.

-Tony

Comment: That method specifically turns an interplocated string into a parameterized SQL statement and you cannot use parameters for table names.  You probably want to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead.

Comment: Actually you need `ExecuteSqlRaw`. Making the mistake mentioned by @juharr (I mean mistake in this case, in most of the scenarios it is recommended functionality) was the main reason of splitting 2.x `ExecuteSql` method to `Raw` / `Interpolated` in 3.x.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you can change your comment to answer